# Show $u \notin H^2$ for $-\text{div}(a\Delta u)=1 $ where $a$ is a step function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am working on a problem which shows interior regularity may fail if you have non-Lipschitz coefficients.

> Let $\Omega = [−1,1]$ and $K = [−1/2,1/2] \in \Omega$. Define $a(x)=1+1_K(x)$ and consider the weak solution $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ to the equation $$-\text{div}(a\nabla u)=1 \text{ on } \Omega, \ \ \ u=0 \text{ on }\partial{\Omega}.$$
>   Show that $u\notin H^2(\hat{\Omega})$ for an open neighbourhood $\hat{\Omega}$ of $K$.

The weak formulation is $\int a\Delta u \Delta v=\int v$ for all $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. I think I need to show that $u''$ has infinite $L^2$-norm on $\hat{\Omega}$. The problem should be that $a$ is a step function, it is $2$ on $K$ and $1$ on $\Omega - K$ and so it has a jump at $-1/2$ and $1/2$. Why is this such a big problem?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathrm{div}$?

Comment: Good point, since the dimension is one I guess it should be $-(au')'=1$.

Comment: It should be $\nabla$ instead of $\Delta$ in the weak formulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the weak formulation, split the integral into parts on $K$ and $\Omega\setminus K$, derive strong formulations separately on these sets together with suitable boundary conditions on the boundary between $K$ and $\Omega\setminus K$. Then you can solve for $u$, it will be piecewise quadratic.

Comment: I got $u(x)=-x^2+7/16$ in $K$ and $u(x)=-x^2/2+1/2$ in $\Omega-K$, and the derivative from the left and right at $x=1/2$ are different. Then this implies that $u'$ has no weak derivative?

Comment: It means that $u$ cannot be in $H^2$, if $u\in H^2$ then $u'\in H^1$ and $u'$ has to be continuous.